# C# MongoDB: Parsing a Json string

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, bson

Let's say I have a big JSON file to parse, and I want to deserialize it into BsonDocument.

Let's say I want to fetch a JSON file from [yahoo weather API](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys).

Here is my code:

```
var weatherAPI_collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("weather_API");
string json_data = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
using (var json_reader = new JsonReader(json_data))
{
    var serializer = new BsonArraySerializer();
    BsonArray bsonArray = serializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(json_reader));
    foreach (BsonValue value in bsonArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.AsBsonDocument);
        weatherAPI_collection.InsertOne(value.AsBsonDocument);
    }
}
```

But I got the error like:

```
'JSON reader was expecting ':' but found '":"'.'
```

What should I do? What mistake did I make?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is write the received document into your MongoDB collection then this is the way to go:

```
string json_data = new WebClient().DownloadString(URL);
weatherAPI_collection.InsertOne(BsonDocument.Parse(json_data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code like below:

```
var weatherAPI_collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("weather_API");
string json_data = webClient.DownloadString(URL);

var docs = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<BsonDocument>>(json_data);
weatherAPI_collection.InsertMany(docs);
```

Deserialize in List depend on you json data if json data in array then use list otherwise you can do like

```
var weatherAPI_collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("weather_API");
string json_data = webClient.DownloadString(URL);

var docs = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json_data);
weatherAPI_collection.InsertOne(docs);
```

In your code you are try to convert in BsonValue which is representing a field in one BsonDocument